# How to read taglib data in JSP during maven build

Tags: jsp, maven, taglib

I have a custom taglib to collect all the JS file names loaded in a particular webpage written in JSP. I want to collect the data from this taglib during maven build to aggregate the JS files and minify it.

Is there anyway to collect the data from the taglib by precompiling the JSP.

If not, is there anyway to do aggregation of JS files called in JSP?

Answer (score 0):

A tag is not executed when the JSP is compiled, but when the JSP is executed. It's hard to understand what your tag does exactly, and why you can't just aggregate and minify all the JS files in advance (each time one of these files is modified during development, and at buid time when generating the deliverable), and just use the single agregated and minified JS file in your JSPs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot use the files generated during development because, there will be many teams working in different branches and all files will be merged at one point. I have to generate aggregated file after merge and minify it. I will try to implement with different approach then.

Comment: I don't see how it is a problem. If, on any given branch, each time a JS file is modified, the agregation and minification is done. And if it's also done at build time by your Maven build, The JSPs will always refer to the most up-to-date aggregated and minified JS file.

Comment: Thanks JB. I have to use a different mechanism to implement this, as I dont want to use the files generated during development.

Comment: You should edit your question and describe your problem better, because I don't understand what your problem is. I suggested twice to agregate and minify the JS files **at build time, using Maven**. How is it a problem?